# PrepareForSegue with UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to use prepareForSegue with an image taken from the camera roll or camera using the UIImagePickerController. This is what I have right now and I don't know how to finish it, I hope you can help me

ViewController.h

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

-(IBAction)escoger:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)camara:(id)sender;
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagepicker;
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"escoger"]) {

        //UIImagePickerController *intro = [UIImagePickerController  ]

        imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

        imagepicker.delegate = self;

        imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


        [self presentViewController:imagepicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is relatively simple if you use the UIImagePickerController with story board. Just create a new viewcontroller in the story board and add a segue. Then set the viewcontroller class to UIImagePickerController in the identity inspector.

[image]

Then implement the prepareForSegue: method and set the source to the camera as;

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;   
}
```

And that works like a charm.

Comment: It didn't work for me, can you send me a project file to see if I did something wrong?

Comment: I have uploaded the project to dropbox and here is the link to it https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34663271/TestProj.zip.

Comment: Thanks! but when I pressed the button it lets me choose and image but then it doesn't show the image. That's the problem I was having... any ideas?

Comment: That's not a difficult part of the problem. Once the image is chosen a delegate being called gives you access to image. See my implementation, there much change to the original program. It shows the image and works as you expect. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/34663271/TestProj.zip

Answer (score 2):

You can't display the image picker inside `prepareForSegue`.  Not if you want to actually use the picture that's been taken.  What you need to do is rewire things so that the action that currently triggers the segue instead opens the image picker.  Then, in your picker delegate's `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, you manually trigger the segue (`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that when the user press a button the app will let him choose a picture and then display it on another view. I'm using storyboard, so when the button is pressed it will change the view to the other with the picture. So how could I do that?

Comment: Remove the segue from the button. Make the button trigger the picker.  Have the picker's delegate method call performSegueWithIdentifier once the image is chosen.

Comment: Cannot get it working.. can you send me a project file please?

Comment: it's fine, I was not looking for a full app just for a sample code

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing this. Essentially, you're trying to use a segue to do something else (but not perform the actual segue). Instead, connect your button or whatever to an `IBAction`, so it causes the image picker to appear, and then, when actually want to perform the segue, call

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"escoger" sender:self];
```

[UPDATE]
Responding to your comment. You need to do several things to make this work:

1) delete the segue from your storyboard

2) create another segue
    **by dragging from the view controller, not from the button**. This will create a segue between the two view controllers, but it won't
    be attached to any button.

3) Create an IBAction method for your
    button in IB ([a tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/))

4) In that method, show your image
    picker

5) when you return from the image picker, perform the segue
    in code (by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier`). 6) Now, you can
    pass the image to the destination view controller in your
    `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that when the user press a button the app will let him choose a picture and then display it on another view. I'm using storyboard, so when the button is pressed it will change the view to the other with the picture. So how could I do that?

Comment: I still can't get it working... could you please send me a project file?

Comment: I don't have a project file, sorry :)